# To have multiselect bootstrap dropdown options drop outside the div(Prevent scroll bubbling)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, scrollbar, bootstrap-multiselect

I have a bootstrap multiselect dropdown within a div as shown in this link http://jsfiddle.net/The_Outsider/8watL2L1/9/

I would like to have the multiselect dropdown drop it's options outside the div,that is I would not want the outside div(in red) to scroll. I want it to resemble the normal dropdown who's code I have below it.

Here is the code as in the link.

HTML :

```
<div class="FixedHeightContainer">
<h2>Multiselect dropdown</h2>    
<select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">    Cheese     </option>
    <option value="tomatoes">  Tomatoes   </option>
    <option value="mozarella"> Mozzarella </option>
    <option value="mushrooms"> Mushrooms  </option>
    <option value="pepperoni"> Pepperoni  </option>
    <option value="onions">    Onions     </option>
    <option value="cheese">    Cheese     </option>
    <option value="tomatoes">  Tomatoes   </option>
    <option value="mozarella"> Mozzarella </option>
    <option value="mushrooms"> Mushrooms  </option>
    <option value="pepperoni"> Pepperoni  </option>
    <option value="onions">    Onions     </option>
    <option value="cheese">    Cheese     </option>
    <option value="tomatoes">  Tomatoes   </option>
    <option value="mozarella"> Mozzarella </option>
    <option value="mushrooms"> Mushrooms  </option>
    <option value="pepperoni"> Pepperoni  </option>
    <option value="onions">    Onions     </option>
</select>
<h3>
   this is the multiselect dropdown 
</h3>
</div>

<div class="FixedHeightContainer">
<h2>Normal Dropdown</h2>        
<select>
    <option value="cheese">    Cheese     </option>
    <option value="tomatoes">  Tomatoes   </option>
    <option value="mozarella"> Mozzarella </option>
    <option value="mushrooms"> Mushrooms  </option>
    <option value="pepperoni"> Pepperoni  </option>
    <option value="onions">    Onions     </option>
    <option value="cheese">    Cheese     </option>
    <option value="tomatoes">  Tomatoes   </option>
    <option value="mozarella"> Mozzarella </option>
    <option value="mushrooms"> Mushrooms  </option>
    <option value="pepperoni"> Pepperoni  </option>
    <option value="onions">    Onions     </option>
    <option value="cheese">    Cheese     </option>
    <option value="tomatoes">  Tomatoes   </option>
    <option value="mozarella"> Mozzarella </option>
    <option value="mushrooms"> Mushrooms  </option>
    <option value="pepperoni"> Pepperoni  </option>
    <option value="onions">    Onions     </option>
</select>
<h3>
   this is the normal dropdown 
</h3>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.FixedHeightContainer{
   height: 250px;
   width:250px; 
   padding:3px; 
   background:#f00;
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
 }

.dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
   $('.multiselect').multiselect();
});
```

UPDATE:
 1. By making the outer div(.FixedHeightContainer), scroll = visible, I am taking away the option of scroll for the div. I want the scroll of the div but not when using the multiselect drop down. 
Making the position=fixed or position=absolute does not help.

2. I tried playing around with z-index but it did not seem to work.
3. Might be an issue with dropdown elements. Found this on http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-alignment
   Dropdowns are automatically positioned via CSS within the normal flow of the document. This means dropdowns may be cropped by parents with certain overflow properties or appear out of bounds of the viewport. Address these issues on your own as they arise.

   4. Javier's answer worked in my laptop but failed to work in another laptop. The Chrome version of both laptops is the same. Any other possible issues?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it's not possible with CSS to show a scrollable content outside the scrollable area. Sadly. So I went for a Javascript solution, following your fiddle:

```
$(function() {
    $('.multiselect').multiselect();
});

(function setFixedMultiselects() {
    $('select.multiselect').each(function(index) {
        var $button = $(this).next().children().first();
        var $dropdown = $button.next();
        if ($dropdown.css('display') != 'none') {
            var offset = $button.offset();
            $dropdown.css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'top': (offset.top+$button.outerHeight())+"px",
                'left': offset.left+"px"
            });
        }
    });
    setTimeout(setFixedMultiselects, 20);
})();
```

Comment: I am not sure you understood my issue. Your code change will remove the scrollbar in the outer div class="FixedHeightContainer" which is not what I want. I want the scrollbar because I need to use the scroll to see <h3>

Comment: New edit for your fiddle, following the scroll problem

Comment: Well, the issue with absolute is that the dropdown position remains constant on scroll down, does not move along with the scroll

Comment: Your right. I understand what you want and this is not doing it. Let me work a bit more on your fiddle...

Comment: Done via Javascript

Comment: Does not change the issue. Would appreciate If there is a fiddle of your's that work.

Comment: I mean, if you replace the Javascript code in your fiddle with the above and run again your fiddle, the dropdown is shown in full, the container scroll is preserved and the dropdown keeps its position under the select button when scrolled. Can you try again please, if you don't see it, we may be having different results with the same code.

Comment: I did add it and made an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/The_Outsider/8watL2L1/8/ Doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Strange. I get it right in your fiddle. The dropdown shows in full and follows the scroll position under the select button. Tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE11. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: I upvoted the question, because it's an interesting thing that should be possible to achieve only with CSS, but you can't. Upvote is registered but may not show because I'm new to this and don't have the minimum reputation.

Comment: Let me check if there is an issue with browsers on my end because I did try it once yesterday and it seemed to work fine according to my requirements. I am upvoting it because I think it might also be an issue on my end.

Comment: Cheers. Might be a client and/or server cache issue

Comment: I'm quite clueless as to what the issue is, It seems to work on my personal laptop but does not work on the office laptop. The Chrome version of both is the same.

Comment: That is really strange. Is the code updated exactly the same in both laptops? If the code is different, it's a cash issue and could be sorted with the Chome Menu > More Tools > Clear Browsing Data, ticking "Cookies" and "Cached images", and setting the Dropdown option at the top as "Since the begining of time".

Comment: If the code is exactly the same and the behaviour is different, being both the same browser and version, I'm as clueless as you. You could test other browsers if you have them installed.

Comment: Also check that the the URL of both fiddles is exactly the same, you may be linking to the old fiddle in one of the systems.

Comment: I updated the javascript improving code and generalising for all present multiselects. You may update the second fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/The_Outsider/8watL2L1/8/ and see if something changes in your failing laptop. Let me know if not, I'm challenged with this.

Comment: Not the best solution, but works for fixing a real problem in the meantime +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.FixedHeightContainer
{

  height: 250px;
  width:250px; 
  padding:3px; 
  background:#f00;
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: visible;
}
```

Comment: That helps to drop the dropdown outside the div, but it also limits the capacity of the outer div(.FixedHeightContainer) to have a scroll bar in case it needs it for some other purpose

Comment: I edited the question to make my comment seem clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can make css like the following :

```
.stop-scrolling {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

then add this css to div in the event of clicking `multiselect`, and then set the position of `dropdown-menu` to make it visible to suit your need. I have made a fixed position to `dropdown-menu` in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vincentluth/ruo1o8xu/).

```
$('.multiselect').on('focusin',function() {

    $('#div1').addClass('stop-scrolling');
    $('.dropdown-menu').css('overflow', 'auto');
  });

  $('.multiselect').on('focusout',function() {

    $('#div1').removeClass('stop-scrolling');

  });
```

Comment: This option takes out my scrollbar of the outer div(the one in red), which I would still need.